# 'Picker' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

Tags: swiftui

I can't seem to get a SwiftUI Picker to work as expected.

I created a TestView below that more or less copies the example from [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker), but I'm still getting "'Picker' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers" as an error.

Any idea how to resolve this? My weak attempt to make the enum public did nothing.

```swift
import SwiftUI

public enum Flavor: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case chocolate
    case vanilla
    case strawberry

    public var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var selectedFlavor = Flavor.chocolate
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Flavor", selection: $selectedFlavor) {
            Text("Chocolate").tag(Flavor.chocolate)
            Text("Vanilla").tag(Flavor.vanilla)
            Text("Strawberry").tag(Flavor.strawberry)
        }
        Text("Selected flavor: \(selectedFlavor.rawValue)")
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

XCode version: 13.2.1

Comment: Works fine for me in 13.1. Clear derived data and try again?

Comment: Just quit XCode and deleted the DerivedData. After restarting the issue still seems to be present.

Comment: Do you have anything else in your project named "Picker"?

Comment: I do! that is very likely the issue.. uff thanks for being my rubber duck test!

Comment: A good way to catch that is to make sure that the issue still happens in a blank project with just your minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [jnpdx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jnpdx), I had a `Picker` enum previously created for an Image Picker in my app.

Renaming this enum to something else allowed me to use Apple's Picker without any errors.